# Setting an icon for Application in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, icons

I'm trying to build a very basic application using the Cordova framework. Trying to add a custom icon to the application has proved challenging. I have looked at the [documentation here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#configuring-icons-in-the-cli). It says that the icon can be defined by adding the `<icon src="res/icon.png" />` to the config.xml file but doesn't exactly say where. However when I do add this to the config.xml file, when trying to launch the application to ios I get the following error: `CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/HandleBars-Templating.app HandleBars-Templating/Images.xcassets.`

Code Snippet of config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="or.HandleBars.joshua" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HandleBars-Templating</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="res/icon/sports.png" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon src="res/icon/sports.png" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you have mentioned only the android sizes. You also need to add one more platform name for iOS as like `<platform name="ios">` and inside that write all the `icon height` according to different size of iOS devices. 
**As like i have mentioned below please have a look at my Code Snippet of `config.xml`**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="or.HandleBars.joshua" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HandleBars-Templating</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>HandleBars-Templating would like to access your photos to store your avatar picture. </string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appavailability" spec="~0.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="git+https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/SocialSharing.git" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" spec="https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/SocialSharing" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="~6.0.2">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="undefined" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: useful answer for me to get some of the standard sizes and what platforms they refer to.